# R Joining multiple time series with map-function

Tags: r, join, map-function

I have a problem to join time-series-dataframes with a map-function. I have 25 dataframes with cryptocurrency time series data.

```
ls(pattern="USD")
[1] "ADA.USD"   "BCH.USD"   "BNB.USD"   "BTC.USD"   "BTG.USD"   "DASH.USD"     "DOGE.USD"  "EOS.USD"   "ETC.USD"   "ETH.USD"   "IOT.USD"
[12] "LINK.USD"  "LTC.USD"   "NEO.USD"   "OMG.USD"   "QTUM.USD"  "TRX.USD"   "USDT.USD"  "WAVES.USD" "XEM.USD"   "XLM.USD"   "XMR.USD"
[23] "XRP.USD"   "ZEC.USD"   "ZRX.USD"
```

Every object is a dataframe which stands for a cryptocurrency expressed in USD. And every dataframe has 2 clomuns: Date and Close (Closing price). For example: the dataframe "BTC.USD" stands for Bitcoin in USD:

```
head(BTC.USD)
# A tibble: 6 x 2
Date       Close
1 2015-12-31  430.
2 2016-01-01  434.
3 2016-01-02  434.
4 2016-01-03  431.
5 2016-01-04  433.
```

Now I want to join them all into one dataframe by Date with a map-function:

```
lst1 <- mget(ls(pattern = "USD"))
df <- map(.x = lst1,.f = full_join(by="Date"))
```

But ist doesen't work:

```
Error in UseMethod("full_join") : 
no applicable method for 'full_join' applied to an object of class "character"
```

Can somebody help me?

Comment: specify the data object

Comment: What exactly do you want to know?

Comment: The full_join will not accept anything other than a dataframe or tibble, so you are not passing proper data object to full_join

Answer (score 0):

The result of mget is a list of characters, thats why `full_join` fails with error.

Try this:

```
map(lst1, function(x) {full_join(tibble(x),head(BTC.USD),by="Date")}) # Full join might fail becuase lst1 has no column called Date.
```

Also, in the result of mget in the lst1 (that you have) there is no column called `Date` 
Creating a lst1 tibble with Date Column:

```
DateVec=c("2015-12-31")
map(lst1, function(x) {full_join(tibble(x,Date=DateVec),head(BTC.USD),by="Date")})
```